# How can I make an image the same size of the <td>?

Tags: css, html

None of the answers I found helped me so I was hoping that someone will know what to do here.

I have a master page which is designed by a table, I have 3 rows, the first row's height is 20%, the second is 5% and the third is 75%. I want my logo to fill the whole first row which has only one  in it, but the original photo is way bigger than the window's size. I tried to make the image's width and height 100% but it still is bigger for some reason and it makes the row about 40%....

```html
<table style="position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%" border="1">
  <tr style="text-align:center; height:20%;">
    <td colspan="2">
      <img style="width:100%; height:100%" src="Pictures/logo.jpg" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align:center; height:5%">
    <td colspan="2">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="index" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height:75%">
    <td style="width:20%">

    </td>
    <td style="width:80%">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I delete the image, it's all good, the page looks fine but when I add the logo, the width is fine but the height looks the same as the third's height.

Is there any was I can fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should create a jsfiddle.

Comment: You need to use jquery. Because the 20% height need to assign in pixels. If the height is assigned in pixel then your code will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it as `absolute` and expand it to full `width` and `height`

```
<tr style="text-align:center; height:20%;">
    <td colspan="2" style="position:relative">
       <img style="width:100%; height:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;" src="Pictures/logo.jpg" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Also, the wrapping `tr` should be set to `position:relative` so the `img` positioning will be in relation to the `tr`.